# Перебор вложенных ассоциативных массивов и запись в БД MySQL

Tags: php, база-данных, foreach

Друзья, не понимаю, как применить foreach к ассоциативному массиву и написать это в обращении к бд. Раньше было одно поле с "номером" гостиницы, которое отправлялось по name из инпута в БД. Я добавил динамическое создание полей и сейчас вижу в dump$_Post такое:

```
array (size=10)
  'surname' => string 'Иванов' (length=12)
  'name' => string 'Иван' (length=8)
  'patronimic' => string 'Иванович' (length=16)
  'date' => string '10.07.2019' (length=10)
  'login' => string 'login' (length=5)
  'password' => string 'pass' (length=4)
  'adress' => string 'Калининград, Площадь 1' (length=40)
  'hotel_name' => string 'House Hostel' (length=12)
  'rooms' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => 
        array (size=6)
          'num_room' => string '1' (length=1)
          'room_cost' => string '1000' (length=4)
          'sleep_place' => string '1' (length=1)
          'add_sleep_place' => string '1' (length=1)
          'floor' => string '1' (length=1)
          'status' => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => 
        array (size=6)
          'num_room' => string '2' (length=1)
          'room_cost' => string '2000' (length=4)
          'sleep_place' => string '2' (length=1)
          'add_sleep_place' => string '2' (length=1)
          'floor' => string '2' (length=1)
          'status' => string '1' (length=1)
      2 => 
        array (size=6)
          'num_room' => string '3' (length=1)
          'room_cost' => string '3000' (length=4)
          'sleep_place' => string '3' (length=1)
          'add_sleep_place' => string '3' (length=1)
          'floor' => string '3' (length=1)
          'status' => string '1' (length=1)
      3 => 
        array (size=6)
          'num_room' => string '4' (length=1)
          'room_cost' => string '4000' (length=4)
          'sleep_place' => string '4' (length=1)
          'add_sleep_place' => string '4' (length=1)
          'floor' => string '4' (length=1)
          'status' => string '1' (length=1)
  'enter' => string '' (length=0)
```

Как вижу, приходят отдельные массивы на 4 комнаты. Я не понимаю,как их перебрать и отправить в Бд. Код обрабатывающий это дело был такой:

```
 $data = $_POST;

//если кликнули на button
        if (isset($data['enter'])) {

            if (empty($errors)) {
                //ошибок нет, теперь регистрируем
                $user = R::dispense('manager');
                $user->surname = $data['surname'];
                $user->name = $data['name'];
                $user->patronimic = $data['patronimic'];
                $user->date = $data['date'];
                $user->login = $data['login'];
                $user->password = password_hash($data['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT); //пароль нельзя хранить в открытом виде, мы его шифруем при помощи функции password_hash для php > 5.6
                R::store($user);

                $hotel = R::dispense('hotels');
                $hotel->adress = $data['adress'];
                $hotel->hotel_name = $data['hotel_name'];
                R::store($hotel);

                $room = R::dispense('rooms');
                $room->hotel_id = $hotel->id;
```

А дальше должен быть перебор массивов и вывод значений. Не понимаю,как это переписать c помощью foreach...

```
 $room->num_room = $data['num_room'];
                $room->room_class = $data['room_class'];
                $room->room_cost = $data['room_cost'];
                $room->sleep_place = $data['sleep_place'];
                $room->add_sleep_place = $data['add_sleep_place'];
                $room->floor = $data['floor'];
                $room->floor = $data['status'];
                R::store($room);

                $this->view->redirect(' /admin/cabinet');
```

Помогите пожалуйста написать обработку и положить в бд, реально не могу найти подходящий пример для понимания...Новичок(((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно циклом перебирать массив `$data['rooms']` и записывать в свойства объекта значения из каждого вложенного массива:

```php
$properties = ['num_room', 'room_cost', 'sleep_place', 'add_sleep_place', 'floor', 'status'];
foreach ($data['rooms'] as $array) {
    $room = R::dispense('rooms');
    $room->hotel_id = $hotel->id;

    foreach ($properties as $property) {
        $room->{$property} = $array[$property];
    }

    R::store($room);
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо:) Вы очень помогли:) для модератора: удалю сообщение благодарности через сутки. Спасибо.